# why is my tomcat not accessible on port 80?

Tags: tomcat, centos7

I changed my server.xml like this:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="80"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

and restarted tomcat.
I also removed my apache server, so that it does not occupy port 80:

```
sudo yum remove httpd
```

But tomcat still only works on 8080:

```
curl localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
```

Comment: To use port 80, tomcat has to run as root. Did you start it with root privileges? (Btw. many people don't like tomcat running as root).

Comment: Did it start up cleanly? No errors?

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that running tomcat by admin is a security issue.
But I found out, that "running on port 80" can be done by port forwarding. I configured  iptables and it works well.